# krippendorffs alpha confusion - "irr" package

Tags: r

I have been trying to compute Krippendorff's alpha statistic for a small dataset, but am able to get very different alpha scores for what is essentially the same case of agreement for my data.

In a rating scale of 1 to 5, two ratings of 4.5 vs 5 would be considered the same distance or amount of agreement as ratings of 4.5 vs 4, however I am getting drastically different results in both Cohens kappa and Krippendorff's alpha in r using the `irr` package.

Data and code:

```
x<-matrix(c(4.5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5),nrow=2)
y<-matrix(c(4.5,4,5,5,5,5,5,5),nrow=2)
kripp.alpha(x,"ordinal")

kripp.alpha(y,"ordinal")
```

Results:

```
> kripp.alpha(x,"ordinal")

 Subjects = 4 
   Raters = 2 
    alpha = 0 

> kripp.alpha(y,"ordinal")
 Krippendorff's alpha

 Subjects = 4 
   Raters = 2 
    alpha = 0.964
```

I am ultimately hoping to use Krippendorffs alpha as I would like to make comparison performance between 2 raters to a larger group of raters.

Any suggestions, guidance, or references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add a tag .The domain type of this question is unclear for the reader .

Comment: Welcome to SO. I slightly rephrased your question and reformatted your code to make it more readable.

Comment: Big caveat that this is a small sample size. Krippendorff's alpha penalizes score when there are raters that do not vary in their responses, or only vary in one response. Reasoning for this penalty here: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ff16/b268224a15f5ccbabf8b3858e86b6d3b8060.pdf.  If you want to look under the hood, other resource here: https://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1043&context=asc_papers

Answer (score 0):

Double check your object names, or typos in your call. Both of these produce the same alpha value. kripp.alpha is not stochastic (the same input will produce the same result).

```
x<-matrix(c(4.5,4,5,5,5,5,5,5),nrow=2)
y<-matrix(c(4.5,4,5,5,5,5,5,5),nrow=2) 

y_kripp_alpha <- irr:::kripp.alpha(y, "ordinal")
x_kripp_alpha <- irr:::kripp.alpha(x, "ordinal")

y_kripp_alpha$value == x_kripp_alpha$value
# [1] TRUE
```

And in fact, each of the components is the same.

Comment: sorry @Dan Hall, I supplied incorrect data. Datasets have been updated in original post.